# Can't start Blood on Ice. Cant buy Hjerim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It appears I have missed the [graveyard scene](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice#A_Killer_on_the_Loose) for the quest and nothing I do will trigger it.

[Hjerim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hjerim)'s door `requires a key` and talking to the guards and people do nothing.

Talking to [Jorleif](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Jorleif) about buying the house only makes him say that there's a mess.

<sub>creating new question as [these](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47226/blood-on-the-ice-no-interaction-with-the-clues-in-hjerim-possible) [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41219/how-can-i-start-the-blood-on-the-ice-quest) [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52046/why-wont-the-blood-on-the-ice-quest-start-even-though-i-have-killed-nilsine) are similar, but don't share my exact symptoms. Also, it looks like some of them have started them and broken them ([because its so full of bugs](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice#Bugs))</sub>